# TypeError: command1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I'm trying to make a login system for a project but for some reason it trows and error at me `TypeError: command1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` when ever I try to call my function . I know you can do `command1(self)` but when I put in the parameter it doesn't do anything but doesn't give me an error

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def command():
    if name.get() == "admin" and password.get == "password":
        login.quit()

login = Tk()
admin_screen = Toplevel()

login.title("Login")
login.geometry("500x500")
login.configure(bg="white")

admin_screen.geometry("500x500")
admin_screen.title("Admin Screen")
admin_screen.configure(bg="white")

lbl = Label(login, font={"Helvtica", 10}, text="Username")
lbl.pack()
name = Entry(login)
name.pack()

lbl2 = Label(login, font={"Helvtica", 10}, text="password")
lbl2.pack()
password = Entry(login)
password.pack()
password.bind("<Return>", command)

login.mainloop()
```

Comment: you are talking about a function which is not present in the source code mentioned.... the only similar function is named "command" but doesn't take any arguments. Could you provide us more source code or information about the source code and exception?

Comment: srry but  that is all the code there but I'll try renaming the function :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the function `command1` in your code. Did you mean `command()` instead ? If yes, this answer is for you. What the problem is that whenever you bind a function to a key, a parameter is automatically given even if it's not literally typed in. All you have to modify your `command()` function to:

```
def command(*args):
    #rest of the code here
```

The `*args` given above takes all the parameters given by either the system automatically or by the user itself. The `command()` not taking the parameters given by system is what gave you the `TypeError`